# Using different RAM Manufactures

Tags: memory, motherboard

Specifically, I am running 4 GB x 2 of DDR3 1600 MHz G.Skill RipJaws Memory, but as my RAM is almost always full (using Unreal Engine/Visual Studio/Google Chrome), I've decided to upgrade to 16 GB, which means I have two free slots left. (ASUS B85 Pro-Gamer motherboard)

Problem is, I cannot find anywhere in my country this G.Skill variant RAM Memory. Is it okay if I buy, for example, **Kinston HyperX 1600 MHz with same CL10 latency**, will that make any issues to my computer, some RAM failures, BSOD's, anything else?

**I do realize** It's not recommended, but I'm in a sticky situation.

**Edit:** Any big performance difference between triple - quad RAM Memory channel? Getting one stick of 8 GB would be better future-proof upgrade, but might degrade performance?

*All answers I've found was several years ago, and none of them included G.Skill.*

Thanks,
Benjamin.

Comment: Your motherboard supports dual channel memory. It doesn't support triple channel or quad channel. Therefore, simply adding a single 8GB stick to your system won't work unless you remove all of your existing RAM.

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3, it also doesn't matter if a statement about DDR3 was written 2 years or 5 years or yesterday, in this specific case the different between dual, triple and quad channel operation wouldn't change.  So DDR3 operating at the same frequency and which has the same timing delays will perform exactly the same as memory from another manufacture.

Comment: How do you mean, won't work out? I've got 4 RAM slots, doesn't that mean It's quad channel?

Comment: @BenjaminKljuno - No; If you have 4 memory slots, it means your motherboard supports dual channel, not quad channel.  Quad channel would require 8 slots, triple would require 6 slots.

Comment: @Ramhound Right. Apparently, I'm terribly dumb today. Lol, thanks for fixing my mistakes, RAM's ordered. All the best!

Comment: "I've decided to upgrade to 16 GB" - Be sure you verify 2 4GB and 1 8GB configuration will be supported by your motherboard.  You typically should not fill a single slot in a channel, you are better of going with 2 sticks of 4GB then a single 8 GB stick.  The QVL is a guideline, pay attention to the sizes, frequency and timing of the modules tested.  *Outside of that a specific vendor of the module is less important.*

Comment: Having 4 RAM slots does not always mean that the motherboard supports quad channel. Usually, having 4 RAM slots will indicate that the motherboard supports dual channel which is definitely the case with AMD's AM3+ platform. Your motherbord is also not an exception. See https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/B85PRO_GAMER/specifications/

Comment: @Ramhound, So, is it fine if I order? It does says, "Dual Memory Channel Architecture", I thought this might support Quad-Channel architecture, but apparently It can't. You kinda confused me with this one, "your motherboard is also not an exception."

Comment: The memory says this?  There is no different between the modules wihin a Single/Dual/Triple/Quad channel kit of memory.  I didn't say the last comment, which I don't agree is accurate, so I can't explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G.Skill don't make memory, they will be buying the RAM chips from the same places as everyone else. The BIOS will read the speed capabilities from each DIMM and configure the system to run at the highest speed supported by both memories.

In other words it should all work fine.

Comment: I've missed huge point there, thanks for pointing me out! Thank you again for answer, I'll just make sure It don't exceed 1600 MHz frequency limit.
I'll wait few more answers before I mark your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows and wish to be absolutely sure what kind of memory
you need, download the
[Crucial System Scanner](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/store-crucial-advisor-trust) and let it scan your system.
It will suggest compatible RAM and configurations.

I have found it to be very accurate in its memory recommendations.
It will of course recommend RAM sold by Crucial,
but their prices are very competitive.